# AVG Virus warning - should I worry?

Tags: windows-xp, virus, avg-antivirus, vtune

I am using Vtune 9.1 on a XP-32 PC with a quad core i7 processor.
I am attempting to do a Call Graph profile of my own program.
Whenever I start the process by clicking VTune's [Run Activity] button I immediately get a warning from my AVG Resident Shield (AVG ver 10.0.1209) as follows:

[image: AVG Warning]

If I click "Move to vault" then VTune goes on to work perfectly. The Move to vault appears to be just temporary though, because the next time I click [Run Activity] I will get the same sequence all over again, with the same filename and the same location.

AVG never complains about viruses at any other time despite me doing a very wide variety of things on my computer. This has been happening for a few days now.

Could this be a false positive? Should I worry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a false positive is likely, your problem is arising because the file is a temp file that is probably created every time you launch this applications.

My advice to you would be to check on the manufacturers forums and see if others are experiencing this issue. You can also try uploading the file to a online scanner like the [Kaspersky online scanner](http://www.kaspersky.com/virusscanner). You can also download [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/mse.aspx) for free (just make sure you disable AVG if you plan to use it full time) or find another online scanner you trust. If two or more virus scanners catch it as a virus then something may actually be wrong with this file and may be virus.

Comment: ...or they're using the same heuristic scanner. xD  Still valid advice!

Comment: Just posted on vtune forum...

Comment: AVG is preventing me from uploading the file into the kaspersky scanner :-(

Comment: @Mick ouch! I don't know how committed you are to solving this but my next step would be to uninstall AVG, you can always reinstall it after you get this sorted out.

Comment: I just swapped wholesale to MSE - all seems fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The Safe way:

1. Boot from a different, preferably non-Windows OS (a Linux LiveCD...)
2. Mount the partition where the file is stored (read-only)
3. Upload the file to an on-line scanner

   - I'd strongly recommend [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) as they will provide you with results from multiple Anti-virus programs (currently over 40). Free of course :)
4. See results.

False detections are pretty normal, and there's not too much that can be done to avoid them completely without risking the ability to detect real viruses.  (This is the same for any anti-virus, so switching to another one won't solve the problem forever.)

Note: Uninstalling or disabling your current anti-virus is not a good idea unless you **know** the file **not a virus**, in which case I don't think you would be reading this text. :)